# copy artifacts build step using a dynamic project name alternatives

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that when it finishes (Post build Actions) Triggers a parameterized build (Job A)

The build that is getting triggered sets a string parameter called foo for the value of JOB_NAME

"Job A" has a build step to 'copy artifacts from another project' were I set the project name to the variable i'm passing (%foo%)

I can confirm that %foo% is getting the correct value however when the build step executes it fails to substitute the variable

This is the error message I'm getting
Unable to find project for artifact copy: %foo%

I'm looking for alternatives to solve my problem which is
How to pass dynamically project name for copy artifacts from another project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the help for Copy artifacts build step? If you click on the question mark next to the *Project name* field, you will see this text:

> Name of source project for copying of artifact(s). May contain references to build parameters like $PARAM (note that when a parameter is used, the source project must be accessible to all authenticated users; this prevents use of parameters to access artifacts of private jobs)

So, you should try `$foo` instead of `%foo%`.

Comment: thanks, i was under the impression that since my jenkins instance was on a windows server that I had to use the bat variable notation

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem.

The "Question mark text" on Project name that @sti quoted was changed meanwhile and only displays info for maven modules.

The error message i got:

> Unable to find project for artifact copy: XYZ
>
> This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.

gives you a hint about missing permissions, but it might be hard to catch or understand (what kind of project-permission?).

So what was missing for me:

Go into your "source"-Job/Project where you want to copy artifacts FROM, and check that

```
Permission to Copy Artifact
```

is correctly set to the job you want to copy INTO. (Or set to a wildcard like *).

Answer (score 0):

For those using [jenkins-job-builder](http://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/), you can set the required permissions like so:

```
- job:
    name: project-to-copy-from
    properties:
    - copyartifact:
        projects: "*"
```

Then you can use `copyartifact` like so:

```
- job:
    name: project-to-copy-to
    builders:
    - copyartifact:
        project: project-to-copy-from
        which-build: last-successful
```

http://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/properties.html#properties.copyartifact